# pulling strings out of mixed file of strings and binary

Tags: text-processing, shell-script

I'm trying to get my nokia backup file into an acceptable vcard format. It has valid vcard strings that appear in between binary data. For example:

```
!@#JUNKCHARACTERS!@#!@BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Jimmy;;;;
TEL;VOICE:4445551212
END:VCARD!@#JUNKCHARACTERS!@#!@
```

I've been working with a hex editor to do some find and replace, but even then it's tedious. Can I use grep or some other command-line tool to pull out all the strings between `BEGIN:VCARD` and `END:VCARD`?

Comment: Does the junk contain newlines? Are there multiple vcards per backup file?

Comment: @Giles No, and yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry if I'm being naive, but can't you just:

```
strings binary-file > binary-strings-output.txt
```

And then post proccess the strings output? Along the lines of:

```
awk '/BEGIN:VCARD/,$NF ~ /END:VCARD/' binary-strings-output.txt
```

Comment: One man's naivete is another man's brilliance! :D

Comment: @user394 Thank you :) You can also use awk to get just the vcard strings. The syntax above might need some work, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a start: print only the text between `BEGIN:VCARD` and `END:VCARD`. This assumes there's always a newline between the `END:VCARD` and the `BEGIN:VCARD`.

```
sed -n -e 's/.*[^A-Z]BEGIN:VCARD/BEGIN:VCARD/' \
       -e 's/END:VCARD[^A-Z].*/END:VCARD/' \
       -e '/BEGIN:VCARD/,/END:VCARD/p'
```

Comment: If/when you have the time, can you write more about how this sed syntax works? I'm trying to understand it but I haven't been able to. I tried achieving the same with awk range syntax.

Comment: @VitorBraga The `s` commands remove the undesired bits on the BEGIN and END lines. Then the `p` command prints the bits in each range from BEGIN to END. The `M,N` syntax (note my edit) is similar to Awk's `,` and Perl's `..` for line ranges.